# Remove consecutive duplicate entries from pandas in each cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that looks like

```
d = {'col1': ['a,a,b', 'a,c,c,b'], 'col2': ['a,a,b', 'a,b,b,a']}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

expected output

```
d={'col1':['a,b','a,c,b'],'col2':['a,b','a,b,a']}
```

I have tried like this :

```
arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c','c']
print([x[0] for x in groupby(arr)])
```

How do I remove the duplicate entries in each row and column of dataframe?

`a,a,b,c` should be `a,b,c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't want to include values which repeat in a sequence, you can try with this custom function:

```
def myfunc(x):
    s=pd.Series(x.split(','))
    res=s[s.ne(s.shift())]
    return ','.join(res.values)

print(df.applymap(myfunc))
```

---

```
    col1   col2
0    a,b    a,b
1  a,c,b  a,b,a
```

Another function can be created with `itertools.groupby` such as :

```
from itertools import groupby
def myfunc(x):
    l=[x[0] for x in groupby(x.split(','))]
    return ','.join(l)
```

Comment: Too similiar.  Let me delete.  Good answer.  +1

Comment: i am glad I thought like you did. :) @ScottBoston :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to help with this, then use .applymap to apply it to all columns (or .apply one column at a time):

```
d = {'col1': ['a,a,b', 'a,c,c,b'], 'col2': ['a,a,b', 'a,b,b,a']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def remove_dups(string):
    split = string.split(',')  # split string into a list
    uniques = set(split)       # remove duplicate list elements
    return ','.join(uniques)   # rejoin the list elements into a string

result = df.applymap(remove_dups)
```

This returns:

```
    col1 col2
0    a,b  a,b
1  a,c,b  a,b
```

Edit: This looks slightly different to your expected output, why do you expect a,b,a for the second row in col2?

Edit2: to preserve the original order, you can replace the set() function with unique_everseen()

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
```

.
.
.

```
uniques = unique_everseen(split)
```

Comment: `a,b,c,c` should be `a,b,c` the order is not correct from function.

Comment: I've edited by answer to let you preserve the original order, if desired.